# Visual Studio rename folder and controls - is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have created my first website in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

In the web project I have a folder structure. Insite these folders I have usercontrols, web services etc.

Having become clearer as I've designed my site, I want to rename 1 ot more of the folders but I've notices the paths to the controls inside each folder are not refactored when I change the name of a folder. At the moment the only way I can see to do this is change each individually.

In this example 'Controls' is the path:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Account_Bar.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Account_Bar" %>
public partial class Controls_Account_Bar : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

Is there a shortcut that allows me to rename a folder and the control path together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you need to get a tool like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) or Telerik's [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) to be able to do that kind of refactoring automatically.